# Importing project from eclipse to android studio (unresolved resources)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, gradle

So I am stuck, I am trying to import an eclipse project to Android studio, and I am getting this error.

```
Error:(22, 23) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'src' with value '@drawable/item').
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command    '/Users/joselibra/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/22.0.1/aapt'' finished   with non-zero exit value 1
```

I have attempted to sync project, delete build file, clean project, rebuild project, invalidate cache and restart.

I followed the direction on how to migrate to Android studio via this link among others, https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html.

This is what my gradle file looks like

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.wtf.edu"
    minSdkVersion 11
    targetSdkVersion 22
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile "com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0"
}
```

Any help or clues would be much appreciated, thank you.

Comment: you are missing `@drawable/item` from drawable  put that try to rebuild

Comment: Either you should check if you have this `item` in your drawable folder, and if it is there and yet you are facing problem. Then tell me if this `item` is your launcher icon?

Comment: So, I have an item.png in my drawable folder, but there is no 'item' in my drawable res folder

Answer (score 0):

Import eclipse project in to android studio project .you can try this one 
n newer versions of *Android Studio, the best way to bring in an Eclipse/ADT project is to import it directly into Android Studio; we used to recommend you export it from Eclipse to Gradle first, but we haven't been updating ADT often enough to keep pace with Android Studio.*
[enter link description here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKIT0_rgfII)
In any event, if you choose "Import Project" from the File menu or from the Welcome screen when you launch Android Studio, it should take you through a specialized wizard that will prompt you that it intends to copy the files into a new directory structure instead of importing them in-place, and it will offer to fix up some common things like converting dependencies into Maven-style includes and such.

It doesn't seem like you're getting this specialized flow. I think it may not be recognizing your imported project as an ADT project, and it's defaulting to the old built-into-IntelliJ behavior which doesn't know about Gradle. To get the specialized import working, the following must be true:

The root directory of the project you import must have an AndroidManifest.xml file.
Either:
The root directory must contain the .project and .classpath files from Eclipse
or
The root directoy must contain res and src directories.
If your project is complex, perhaps you're not pointing it as the root directory it wants to see for the import to succeed.